# I don't receive the context from a react navigation push

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-hooks

I have a stacknavigator in my React Native App with some components:

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({Test1,Test2,Test3})
```

I also have context api wrapping my component:

```
<UserContext.Provider  value={{test,setTest}}>
   <Test1/>
</UserContext.Provider>
```

Inside Test1 I have the Test2 component, here in Test2 the context is shown. But also in Test1 I have a button to push to Test3.

TEST1:

```
<Test2/>
<Fab
    onPress={() => navigation.push('Test3')}
    containerStyle={{}}
    style={{backgroundColor: '#5067FF'}}
    position="bottomRight">
    <Icon name="share" />
</Fab>
```

TEST2:

```
const Test2 = ({navigation}) => {
  const context = useContext(UserContext);
  console.log(context) //it's ok
}
```

And the problem is that the context does not reach in Test3, it shows me null

TEST3

```
const Test3 = ({navigation}) => {
  const context = useContext(UserContext);
  console.log(context) //null
}
```

What's going on ?
How can I receive the context in Test3?

Comment: How is Test3 rendered in the hierarchy

Comment: Test3 is called through navigation.push('Test3'), by the button inside Test1. The hierarchy is: App(father component with the stackNavigator and wrapping Test1 with a Provider) -> Test1 (Children of App, this have Test2 component and a button for navigate to Test3) -> Test2 (Children of Test1, here the context is ok) ; Test3 (via navigation from Test1, here the context is null)